# Dynamic MySQLi Statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Forgive me as this is probably a 101 question but I'm having no luck wrapping my head around it.

I'm working with a mysqli->prepare statement and

`"Select * FROM someTable WHERE someTable.column = 1"` - Works beautifully

We can make it dynamic by passing the variable with the use of a ? and a bind param.
`"Select * FROM someTable WHERE someTable.column = ?"` - Works beautifully

My desire was to build a statement that let me pass "someTable.column = 1" dynamically

```
"Select * FROM someTable WHERE ?"
```

I figured the method was a total bust but tried testing it by passing on the variable "1 = 1" and it worked?!

So if I can pass "1=1", then why couldn't I pass "someTable.column = 1"

I've done this with MySQL in the past by building the statement and inserting it all at one time. I was just hoping there was another way.

Comment: use 2 variables one for column and one for value and pass it just like you described.Thats the easiest way from the top of my head like this `"Select * FROM someTable WHERE $column = $value"`

Comment: Another desire was the ability to stack conditions on top of one another and pass them through.  I'm assuming I will need to assemble the statement 100% outside of the mysqli prepare statement but was hoping there was a way to pass in a number of conditions through one bind variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me as my reputation is not enough to post a comment, but why not just using string concat in your case?

Such as `$query="Select * FROM someTable WHERE 1=1 ";` and then

```
if($additionalInfo==true){ $query.= "AND someTable.column=1 "; }
```

Please inform me if I misunderstand your question, and I will remove this possible misleading post.

Comment: That's a god method, thank you. May very well end up using it.